# Comparar os resultados

Tags: php, mysql

Caros colegas.

Estou trazendo duas perguntas do banco de dados Mysql da seguinte forma:

```
....
Qual sua idade? <input type="text" name="Perguntas[]" value="<?php echo $jmPerguntas->Perguntas; ?>">
Você tem o segundo grau? <input type="text" name="Perguntas[]" value="<?php echo $jmPerguntas->Perguntas; ?>">
Especifique:
<textarea name="Especifique[]" style="width: 200px; height: 80px"></textarea>
    .....
```

E pego os resultados com PHP dessa forma:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['Perguntas']); $i++){

if($_POST['Perguntas'][$i] == 'Você tem o segundo grau?'){
   echo "aqui";   
}else{
   echo "não aqui";
}

} // fim do for()
```

O único problema é que o trecho:

```
if($_POST['Perguntas'][$i] == 'Você tem o segundo grau?'){
   echo "aqui";   
}else{
   echo "não aqui";
}
```

Está dando "**não aqui**", mesmo a pergunta sendo '**Você tem o segundo grau?**'.

Alguém saberia me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Obrigado!

Comment: Qual seria uma valor para `$jmPerguntas->Perguntas` ? sim ou não?

Comment: **1)** Dê um `var_dump` ou `print_r` em *$_POST*. **2)** Isso é algum tipo de verificação para validação do form?

Comment: Poderia explicar também pq os campos tem o mesmo nome(`perguntas[]`)?

Comment: Mas neste seu exemplo, porque você não coloca o idPergunta, ao invés de trazer a pergunta em si? Pois ai facilitaria na sua comparação acima... if($_POST['Perguntas'][$i]=='1'){ echo "aqui"; }.. Mas exemplifiquei de outra forma, talvez, com o exemplo você consiga adaptar e chegar onde queres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborei o seguinte exemplo: Veja se lhe ajuda.

Código PHP

```
<?
    if(isset($_POST['pergunta'])){

            if(!empty($_POST['pergunta'][0])){
               echo "<strong>Idade:</strong> ".$_POST['pergunta'][0]."<br>";   
            }

            if(!empty($_POST['pergunta'][1])){
               echo "<strong>Segundo Grau:</strong> ".$_POST['pergunta'][1]."<br>";   
            }

            if(!empty($_POST['especifique'])){
               echo "<strong>Especificação:</strong> ".$_POST['especifique']."<br><br><br>";   
            }

    }
?>
```

Código HTML

```
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <form action="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" name="perguntas" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        Qual sua idade? <br>
        <input type="text" name="pergunta[]" value="<? if(isset($_POST['pergunta'])){ echo $_POST['pergunta'][0]; } ?>">
        <br><br>
        Você tem o segundo grau? <br>
        <input type="text" name="pergunta[]" value="<? if(isset($_POST['pergunta'])){ echo $_POST['pergunta'][1]; } ?>">
        <br><br>
        Especifique:<br>
        <textarea name="especifique" style="width: 200px; height: 80px"><? if(isset($_POST['especifique'])){ echo $_POST['especifique']; } ?></textarea><br><Br>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
</html>
```

Desta forma, temos a array pergunta que por sua vez, no array 0, é a primeira pergunta, se respondida, retorna na tela.. assim continua com os demais campos.

Comment: Desculpem na demora. Obrigado a todos que se disponibilizaram em ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborei um código simples para você entender o que acontece.

```
<?php

if($_POST){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['Perguntas']); $i++){

        if($_POST['Perguntas'][$i] == 'Você tem o segundo grau?'){
            echo "aqui";   
        }else{
            echo "não aqui";
        }

    } // fim do for()
}
```

?>

exemplo

```
</head>

<body>

    <form method="POST" action="index.php" >
        <label>Qual sua idade?</label> <input type="text" name="Perguntas[]" value="Qual sua idade?" >
        <br/>
        <label>Você tem o segundo grau? </label><input type="text" name="Perguntas[]" value="Você tem o segundo grau?" >
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>


</body>
```

O motivo dele mostrar essa mensagem na segunda pergunta se dá na comparação que o seu PHP está programado para fazer. Observe como sua variável POST está preenchido durante o submit:

```
    array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Qual sua idade?' (length=15)
  1 => string 'Você tem o segundo grau?' (length=25)
não aqui
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Qual sua idade?' (length=15)
  1 => string 'Você tem o segundo grau?' (length=25)
aqui
```

Observe que na sua primeira iteração ele compara se:

'Você tem o segundo grau? == 'Qual sua idade?'

Por isso a resposta é não aqui.

Finalmente na segunda iteração o resultado é o esperado.

Não existe erro no PHP apenas seria interessante você rever a lógica.

Comment: Foi o que eu sugeri... Sugeri a ele também que fizesse então esta comparação através do idPergunta, o que facilitaria bastante e resolveria a questão, mas sua explicação está corretíssima.